# Different ways of addressing pointers C/C++

Tags: c, embedded, pointers

I'm a little confused about accessing specific addresses using c style pointers.

I have a 32 bit chip which I'm tryin to program. I need to flip some bits or whatever in ram. The following solution works fine.

```
uint32 strbase = 0x00168380;
volatile uint32 *ram = (uint32*)0x03000000;


ram[(strbase+0x48)/4] = 0x10000000; 
ram[(strbase+0x4c)/4] = 0x10000000; 
ram[(strbase+0x50)/4] = 0x10000000; 
ram[(strbase+0x54)/4] = 0x10000000; 
ram[(strbase+0x58)/4] = 0x10000000; 
ram[(strbase+0x5c)/4] = 0x10000000; 
ram += (strbase+0x60)/4;
```

However, I'm a bit confused. I tried writing a few different subroutines that I thought was equivalent but didn't work. This following method only kinda works.

```
uint32 strbase = 0x00168380;
volatile uint32 *ram = (uint32*)0x03000000;

*(uint32*)(0x03000000 + 0x001683c8) = 0x10000000; 
*(uint32*)(0x03000000 + 0x001683CC) = 0x10000000; 
*(uint32*)(0x03000000 + 0x001683D0) = 0x10000000; 
*(uint32*)(0x03000000 + 0x001683D4) = 0x10000000; 
*(uint32*)(0x03000000 + 0x001683D8) = 0x10000000; 
*(uint32*)(0x03000000 + 0x001683DC) = 0x10000000; 
ram += (strbase+0x60)/4;
```

This following method doesn't work at all.

```
uint32 strbase = 0x00168380;
volatile uint32 *ram = (uint32*)0x03000000;

 ram += strbase+0x48; 
 *ram++ = 0x10000000; 
 *ram++ = 0x10000000; 
 *ram++ = 0x10000000; 
 *ram++ = 0x10000000; 
 *ram++ = 0x10000000; 
 *ram++ = 0x10000000;
```

I've been stewing on this for a while. I think it might be the compiler doing some kinda optimization. Hopefully one of you guys can explain to me what's wrong or point me to resources to figure this one out.

Comment: In your third sample, the value `(strbase + 0x48)` needs to be divided by four.

Comment: In the middle example, the compiler generates a warning if you don't cast the address into a uint32_t*. Is this what you mean by "kinda works" ?

Comment: uint32 is a typedef I made. All I have is the compiler and my code.

Comment: I also don't understand why in example 3 I would have to divide by 4. `ram += strbase+0x48;` translates to `ram = ( 0x03000000 + 0x00168380 + 0x48 );` which should set the address i want to point to. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Steven741: you are wrong. Pointer arithmetic in C respects the typesize - `ram[x]` is just the same as `*(ram +x)` or `ram+=x;*(ram);` - that's why you have to divide by 4. And when you write "kinda works" - please describe exactly *what* does work and what not, what exactly do you *observe*?

Comment: Wow i didn't know there was such a thing as pointer arithmetic before. I thought it was all the same!

Comment: What I'm trying to do is write to some other chip via cpu. When I use method 1 I get the expected output. When I use method 2 I get an output that is same as method 1 but certain chunks of the output array are wrong.

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

Comment: Thanks. I think this is just what the doctor ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second solution, you are typedefing to

```c
(uint32*)
```

instead of

```c
(volatile uint32*)
```

That allows compiler to optimize memory access and reorder writes. If this code is part of a bigger routine and the hardware expects you to write sequentially, this is probably the problem.

In the third solution, as Doc Brown already stated, you have to divide by four to get:

```c
ram += (strbase+0x48)/4;
```

Note that generally speaking, you should always use use sizeof(uint32) instead of literal constant. It helps readability and C standard does not provide you exact sizes of integral types.

Comment: `sizeof(uint32)` is an overkill. If `uint32` is the same as `uint32_t`, it has exactly 32 bits; its `sizeof` can be different from 4 only when using 16-bit or 32-bit bytes. While this is theoretically possible, you are programming a specific embedded platform, and you don't need to pretend that your code is portable in any way.

Comment: @anatolyg Ah I see now - POSIX specifies exact bit width of uint32_t. My bad.
Anways, using sizeof(variable_name) helps readibility and should be preffered when possible.